# for cycle in folders modifing a number of a txt file with an incrementing number

Tags: bash, scripts, sed

I have a main directory in which there are many sub-directories, each one containing the same files of the others.
They are only named in a different wat and more in depth in a progressive way, like /maindirectory/1/ , /maindirectory/2/, maindirectory/3/, etc.

In each sub-directory there is the same .txt file.

In this .txt file there is a line with a parameter I need to modify for each sub-directory with a different value.
Let's call the parameter I need to modify "k".

In maindirectory/1/file_name.txt k=1 for example.

I need to increment k for all the other sub-directories with a constant value, let's call it "h", so in maindirectory/2/file_name.txt k=1+h, in maindirectory/3/file_name.txt k=1+h+h and so on.

I've seen how to perform a for cycle within directories by using `for d in /maindirectory/*/;do (cd "$d" && some_command); done` and how to modify a predefine variable `sed -i -e 's/k=1/k=1+h/line_number' ./file_name.txt`.

Is it possible to combine these two command lines to achieve my goal?
Or do you know a smarter way or just a different one to do that?
I do not know anything about programming unless in a Matlab environment so be gentle please :)
Thanks very much.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu. The Question is very difficult to read. Please use some paragraphs.

Comment: yes i am having a difficult time understanding too

Comment: sorry for that; hopefully now it is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly:

- Folder names are Integers
- h is a constant
- k must be increased by (h * (folder - 1) )

Then this should work:

```
# Set constant variable h
h=1

cd /maindirectory/

# Loop directories
for d in *; do

    # open subshell
    (
    cd $d;

    # Get current value of k
    k=$(grep -Po "(?<=k\=)[0-9]+" file_name.txt);

    # Calculate new value of k
    new_k=$(bc<<<"$k+$h*($d-1)");

    # Update text file with new value of k
    sed -i -e "s/k=$k/k=$new_k/" file_name.txt;

    # Close subshell
    )
done
```

Comment: This does exactly what I need. Thanks so much!!!